# custom paint function in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, java-2d

i am a newbie in java. i am working on an assignment in which i am reading commands from file and drawing the shapes on jpanel.
the file is like

```
 FRAME 200 100        // open a frame, note: parser must ignore any comments
    COLOR 255 0 0 // set color to red
    RECTANGLE 20 30 40 20 // draw a red rectangle
    COLOR 128 128 128 // set color to gray
    CIRCLE 100 50 25 // draw a gray circle
    FRAME 100 100    // open a second frame
    COLOR 0 0 255 // set color to blue
    ELLIPSE 50 50 30 20 // draw a blue ellipse
    COLOR 0 255 0 // set color to green
    LINE 10 20 90 80 // draw a green line
```

i have written the following code.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Source Demo");
frame.setTitle("Drawing Graphics in Frames");
frame.setBounds(100,50,500,300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
///////////////////
    File file = new File("Paint_instruction.txt");  
    //  Get data from this file using a file reader.   
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);  
    // To store the contents read via File Reader  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    //writer to write in file

    while((data = br.readLine()) != null)   
    { 
        /*String[] tokens = data.split("\\s{1,}");
           for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
           {System.out.println(tokens[i]);}*/

         String []tokens = data.split("\\s{1,}");

           if(tokens[0].equals("FRAME"))
           {JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("JFrame Source Demo");
           frame2.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
           frame2.setVisible(true);


           }
           else if(tokens[0].equals("RECTANGLE"))
           {
           //draw circle
           }
           else if(tokens[0].equals("CIRCLE"))
           {
               //draw circle
           }
           else if(tokens[0].equals("LINE"))
           {
               //draw Line
           }
           else if(tokens[0].equals("ELLIPSE"))
           {
               //draw ELLIPSE
           }
```

i do not know how to use paint function to draw these shapes. I have tried to pass array to paint function. but it did not work.
I have goggled it but did not find any appropriate help

Comment: You should try to make your task on your own. That way you'd be much better off.

Comment: I'd suggest that you shouldn't be reading from a file while within any paint method, as you want these to be as fast as you can make it

Answer (score 4):

> and drawing the shapes on jpanel.

So where is your JPanel?

> I have goggled it but did not find any appropriate help

I find that hard to believe. Links to the [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial are found all over this and other forums.

It is harder to learn how to do painting when reading commands from a file, so I suggest that you first learn the basics of doing painting before you tackle painting from a command file.

Comment: Probably what OP meant is that the assignment hasn't yet been posted somewhere on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `paintComponent` method of `JPanel` and within that method draw all these shapes using `java.awt.Graphics` argument passed in `paintComponent` method. And add that `JPanel` to the `JFrame`. Look at the [official tutorial for paint mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) in java